# Convert a JSON-like string into a PHP array

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON data that is saved in a text area as a string. Whilst it looks like JSON, it's technically speaking; not JSON.

How can I convert this string into an array in PHP? Here is an example of latitude and longitude coordinates that will be used on a Google Map:

**String:**

```
[{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000}]
```

**PHP:**

```php
// get the coordinates
$coords = coordinates( 123 );

// Encode it into actual JSON
$coords = json_encode( $coords );

// Decode it into an array
$coords = json_decode( $coords, true );
```

If I then use `var_dump( $coords );`, it prints out the data as a string. What am I doing wrong here? I've looked at the plethora of other questions about this and none solve this issue. It just doesn't seem to work the same way.

Comment: Your string isn’t valid JSON, so it won’t work with any JSON functions.

Comment: @ThomasEdwards: it is _almost_ valid, though. Maybe one can find a more forgiving json parser.

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" — You're trying to parse something that you have acknowledged is not JSON as if it were JSON.

Comment: "I've looked at the plethora of other questions about this and none solve this issue" — Which ones? Is your question significantly different from them? Could you not issue a bounty to attract more attention to a question rather then asking a new one? Don't they all boil down to two solutions — (1) change the input to JSON (2) write a custom parser — anyway?

Comment: How can I convert this string into valid JSON then? The `json_decode` function will convert it to an array, but I suppose my issue here is convert this string into valid JSON data to begin with.

Comment: My first idea would be: can you try and change how you get the data? I know that’s a silly question, but worth asking. If not, then your best bet is to read it with regex and build the array yourself.

Comment: @DanielJames — Ideally by going to the source and fixing the code which generates it there.

Comment: I didn't realise what I was missing here was quotes around the `lat` & `lng` key names. I am able to change the data so doing this has made it work. Thanks for the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't fix what generates this data, you can try to make it valid, as long as it's not too far from valid, at least. From your example, only the double quotes for the keys are missing, you can try with that:

```
$str = '[{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000}]';

$str = preg_replace('/({\s*|,\s*)([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\s*:)/', '$1"$2"$3', $str);

var_dump($str); //string(149) "[{"lng": -0.000000, "lat": 10.000000},{"lng": -0.000000, "lat": 10.000000},{"lng": -0.000000, "lat": 10.000000},{"lng": -0.000000, "lat": 10.000000}]"

$data = json_decode($str);

if($data !== null){
    //$data decoded properly
}
```

This is quickly done, you might need to adapt the criteria for characters in keys and such following your needs.

EDIT: also removed the lazy quantifier from `[0-9a-zA-Z]+` which was left from a needlessly wider range previously used

Comment: Throw a `json_decode` in there and it's perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As you clearly specified how your syntax looks like, and assuming that there will be always two-level nesting and similar structure, it's not too hard to write a parser for that syntax by hand.

If the structure indeed is more complicated than I assumed, please specify how complex your pseudo-JSON is going to be.

A hand-written parser could, e. g., look like that:

```
<pre><?php
$data = "[{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000},{lng: -0.000000, lat: 10.000000}]";
$arr = array();

foreach(preg_split("/},{/", substr($data, 2, -2)) as $entry) {
    $subarr = array();
    foreach(preg_split("/, /", $entry) as $subentry) {
        list($key, $val) = preg_split("/: /", $subentry);
        $subarr[$key] = $val;
    }
    $arr[] = $subarr;
}

print_r($arr);
```